# using $routeProvider does not put ng-controller in markup

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am using $routeProvider in my angular app. I had route like this:

```
 .when("/MyProfile", {
         templateUrl: "app/MyProfile.html",
         controller: "MyProfileCtrl"
     })
```

but to my surprise, I saw when it renders HTML template into ng-view it add no ng-controller attribute to markup. actually, I did not care how communication to the controller is handled by $routeProvider until I saw directives with the shared scope which I had put in the template can not see controller's scope. Anyway in order to make my directives to work properly, I had to remove the controller from the path and add it manually to the template.

I still have a misgiving about this solution because $routeProvider is a very reputable plugin and I expected it to work better than this.

Comment: This is the functionality of $routeProvider which applies dynamic controller to a template. If it will add controller markup how it is dynamic then?
Go through docs carefully.

Comment: Ok. Then in the case of using directives why directives can not use the scope of that dynamic controller? How do you handle putting directives into templates?

Comment: This is a different issue what you have asked in question. Second directives can also use scope of controllers

Comment: It seems you did not read my question well. I said the reason I had to put the controller into markup instead of route definition was that directives could not use controllers scope.

Comment: Ok but as per my knowledge you add controller on markup or in route directives can still use their scope.

Comment: well, I tried both of them very carefully But unfortunately, the only way that directives could use  controller's scope was to put ng-controller into markup.

Comment: I am really new into angular js. I really expected it to work just the way you say. But it did not.

Comment: You should make an plunker then it would be really helpful